# How to remove text between two specific words in a dataframe column by python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have text in a column I am cleaning, I need to remove all words between the words "Original" and "Subject" wherever they appear in the column which is only some of the rows.

I am currently trying

```
   a = df['textcol']
   import re
   df['textcol'] =re.sub('Original.*?Subject','',str(a), flags=re.DOTALL)
```

this function is making every string within every tow the exact same as the first row it instead of looking at each row individually and altering it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) directly:

```py
df['textcol'] = df['textcol'].str.replace(r'(?s)Original.*?Subject', '', regex=True)
```

Here, `(?s)` stands for `re.DOTALL` / `re.S` in order not to have to import `re`, it is their inline modifier version. The `.*?` matches any zero or more chars, as few as possible.

If `Original` and `Subject` need to be passed as variables containing literal text, do not forget about `re.escape`:

```py
import re
# ... etc. ...
start = "Original"
end = "Subject"
df['textcol'] = df['textcol'].str.replace(fr'(?s){re.escape(start)}.*?{re.escape(end)}', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: amazing thank you!!